# Assigning a value to a PIC clause less than specified length

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm a beginner to COBOL, and i'm wondering what would happen if i did something like the following: 
(I know that the below code isnt runnable cobol, its just there for example)

```
foo pic x(5)
accept foo
```

and the user types in a string that is only 3 characters long (e.g. yes)
would the value of foo be just "yes"? or would it fill the all 5 characters as specified at creation (for example: "(space)(space)yes" or "yes(space)(space)", or is it something else?

Thanks!

here is my code

```
000100        IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                           
000200       *--------------------                               
000300        PROGRAM-ID. ZIPCODES.                              
000400       *--------------------                               
000500        ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                              
000600       *--------------------                               
000700        CONFIGURATION SECTION.                             
000800        INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                              
000900        FILE-CONTROL.                                      
001000            SELECT PRT ASSIGN TO UT-S-PRTAREA.             
001100                                                           
001200        DATA DIVISION.                                     
001300       *-------------                                      
001400        FILE SECTION.                                      
001500        FD  PRT                                            
001600            RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS                  
001700            DATA RECORD IS LINE-PRT.
001800        01  LINE-PRT              PIC X(80).                
001900                                                            
002000        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                            
002100       *-----------------------                             
002200                 EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA  END-EXEC.          
002300                                                            
002310        01 done.                                           
002320           02 donevar            PIC x(5) VALUE 'done '.    
002400        01 ZIP-RECORD.                                      
002500           02 ZIP                PIC X(5).                  
002600           02 ZCITY              PIC X(20).                 
002700           02 ZSTATE             PIC X(2).                  
002800           02 ZLOCATION          PIC X(35).                 
002900                                                            
003000        01 H1.                                              
003100           02 COLUMN-1           PIC X(8) VALUE 'Zip-Code'. 
003200           02 FILLER             PIC X(2).                  
003300           02 COLUMN-2           PIC X(5) VALUE 'State'.
003400           02 FILLER             PIC X(2).                       
003500           02 COLUMN-3           PIC X(4) VALUE 'City'.          
003600           02 FILLER             PIC X(16).                      
003700           02 COLUMN-4           PIC X(14) VALUE 'Location Text'.
003800           02 FILLER             PIC X(29).                      
003900                                                                 
004000        01 L1.                                                   
004100           02 ZIP-L1             PIC X(5).                       
004200           02 FILLER             PIC X(5).                       
004300           02 STATE-L1           PIC X(2).                       
004400           02 FILLER             PIC X(5).                       
004500           02 CITY-L1            PIC X(20).                      
004600           02 LOCTXT-L1          PIC X(35).                      
004700           02 FILLER             PIC X(28).                      
004800                                                                 
004900        PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                      
005000       *------------------                                       
005100        BEGIN.
 005200                 OPEN OUTPUT PRT.                                
 005220                 PERFORM ZIP-LOOKUP UNTIL ZIP = done.            
 005600        PROG-END.                                                
 005700                 CLOSE PRT.                                      
 005800                 GOBACK.                                         
 005900       *****************************************************     
 006000       * zip code lookup                                   *     
 006100       *****************************************************     
 006200        ZIP-LOOKUP.                                              
 006300                 DISPLAY 'enter 5 digit zip code'                
 006400                 ACCEPT ZIP                                      
 006500                 EXEC SQL                                        
 006600                  SELECT * INTO :ZIP-RECORD FROM ZBANK.ZIPCODE   
 006700                  WHERE ZIP = :ZIP                               
 006800                 END-EXEC.                                       
 006801                 PERFORM PRINT-H1.                               
 006802                 PERFORM PRINT-L1.                               
 006900        PRINT-H1.
007000                 MOVE H1 TO LINE-PRT                     
007100                 WRITE LINE-PRT.                         
007200        PRINT-L1.                                        
007300                 MOVE  ZIP          TO  ZIP-L1           
007400                 MOVE  ZSTATE       TO  STATE-L1         
007500                 MOVE  ZCITY        TO  CITY-L1          
007510                 STRING ZSTATE DELIMITED BY " ",", ",    
007520                 ZCITY DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO LOCTXT-L1  
007700                 MOVE  L1 TO LINE-PRT                    
007800                 WRITE LINE-PRT.
```

I'm trying to write the zstate before the zcity, and having it keep asking for ZIP codes as long as the input isnt 'done'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 5 characters entered will be moved to FOO. If fewer than 5 characters are entered then they will be placed in the left hand positions of FOO and the remaining characters (to the right) will be filled with spaces. If the user enters more than 5 charcters then only the first 5 are moved.

So to use your example if the user typed "yes" then FOO would contain "yes<strike>bb</strike>"

Best thing to do is try it!

**Edit in response to updated question...**
I think your problem is that the condition needed to terminate the loop is set in the beginning of the loop body and
not at the end. Here are a couple of commonly used techniques to solve this problem:

**Pre loop read**

```
          DISPLAY 'Enter a 5 digit zip code'
          ACCEPT ZIP
          PERFORM ZIP-LOOKUP UNTIL ZIP = done.
          ...
          ...
      ZIP-LOOKUP.
          EXEC SQL                                        
            SELECT * INTO :ZIP-RECORD FROM ZBANK.ZIPCODE   
            WHERE ZIP = :ZIP                               
          END-EXEC.                                       
          PERFORM PRINT-H1.                               
          PERFORM PRINT-L1.
     *    Now get next zip code or 'done'                    
          DISPLAY 'Enter a 5 digit zip code'
          ACCEPT ZIP
          .
```

**Guard against setting terminating condition within the loop**

```
          PERFORM ZIP-LOOKUP UNTIL ZIP = done.
          ...
          ...
      ZIP-LOOKUP.
          DISPLAY 'Enter a 5 digit zip code'
          ACCEPT ZIP
          IF ZIP NOT = DONE
             EXEC SQL                                        
               SELECT * INTO :ZIP-RECORD FROM ZBANK.ZIPCODE   
               WHERE ZIP = :ZIP                               
             END-EXEC                                      
            PERFORM PRINT-H1                               
            PERFORM PRINT-L1
          END-IF
          .
```

Either one of the above should solve your problem. However, I would suggest trying to update your coding style to include
COBOL-85 constructs. The first example above might be coded as follows:

```
          DISPLAY 'Enter a 5 digit zip code'
          ACCEPT ZIP
          PERFORM UNTIL ZIP = done
             EXEC SQL                                        
                  SELECT * INTO :ZIP-RECORD FROM ZBANK.ZIPCODE   
             WHERE ZIP = :ZIP                               
             END-EXEC                                       
             PERFORM PRINT-H1                              
             PERFORM PRINT-L1
             DISPLAY 'Enter a 5 digit zip code'
             ACCEPT ZIP
          END-PERFORM
          .
```

The ZIP-LOOKUP paragraph has been in-lined into the PERFORM statement. For short sections of code I find this style much more
readable.
Also notice single sentence paragraphs (only one period at the end of a paragraph). When COBOL-85 scope terminators are used (eg. END-xxx)
the need for mulitple sentences per paragraph goes away - and in fact - they should be avoided.

Another COBOL construct that you could make use of here is the `88 LEVEL`. You could use it as follows:

```
        01 ZIP-RECORD.                                      
           02 ZIP                PIC X(5). 
              88 DONE            VALUE 'done  '.
        ...
        ...
```

You no longer need `donevar` at all. Replace your original test:

```
                 
        IF ZIP = DONE
```

with:

```
                 
        IF DONE
```

The above will be true whenever the variable `ZIP` contains the value "done<strike>bb</strike>". One advantage of
doing this (other than saving one variable declaration) is that a single `88 LEVEL` name can be assigned
several values, as in:

```
        01 ZIP-RECORD.                                      
           02 ZIP                PIC X(5). 
              88 DONE            VALUE 'done  ',
                                       'quit  ',
                                       'stop  '.
```

When the user enters any one of `done`, `quit` or `stop` the 88 level name `DONE` evaluates to true.

Finally, I presume this is just a skeleton of the program and that the finished version will be checking for I/O errors, bad SQL codes
and do basic ZIP code validation. If not, you can expect a lot of trouble down the road.

**COBOL Reference material**

Unfortunately there are very few good up to date resources for learning COBOL. However, one of the
books I would recommend is [Advanced Cobol 3rd Edition by DeWard Brown](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471314811).
This book provides many examples and explanations regarding COBOL program development. It also identifies whether a 
construct is rarely used, obsolete or essential. This is good to know since you should be developing new code using modern COBOL
programming techniques (I continue to see a lot of new COBOL developed using pre-COBOL 85 coding practice - and it is horrible).

An open source
guide is the [OpenCOBOL Programmers Guide](http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/OpenCOBOL%20Programmers%20Guide.pdf). This targets OpenCOBOL but
much of it is applicable to any flavour of COBOL.

Finally, there are several vendors guides and manuals, many of which are available on the internet. For
example [Enterprise COBOL for z/OS Language Reference](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3LR31/CCONTENTS?DT=20060329140556) and
[Enterprise COBOL for z/OS Programming guide](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3PG31/CCONTENTS?DT=20060329003636) are
freely available. Microfocus COBOL
guides are also available. Search any you will find...

Comment: And as a bonus rawrnerozero;  COBOL has right-to-left with space fill rules when moving `PIC X` character data and less commonly seen, but very well defined in the standard, left-to-right rules with high order truncation and zero fill for numerics, ala `PIC 9`.  MOVE -123 to a PIC S99 gives, -23.

Comment: I'm trying to create a loop that ends when the input "done" is received, but it normally receives a zip code. I use a perform-until loop to perform zipcodelookup until zip = donevar, where zip is the input received and donevar was defined as PIC x(5) value 'done(spacecharacter)'. The loop doesnt end when I type done, though. is my problem not in the pic clause?

Comment: @rawrnerozero Show us your code... The problem may be more to do with coding the PERFORM loop. Also, beware that 'DONE ' is not the same as 'done ' for comparason purposes.

Comment: Do i need to insert the things in the ZIP-LOOKUP into the perform loop? Also: do you know of any good resources for learning more about cobol? thanks!

Comment: thank neal, yes this is just a skeleton of the program. do you have any suggestions on where I could read up more on cobol? I'm fairly advanced with java and lisp, but I cant seem to find a nice cobol book / resource yet.

Comment: @rawrnerozero Added some COBOL reference material for you. So you are a lisp programmer too. I have not used lisp in many years but remember how powerfully mind blowing that language can be once you get to truly understand how to use it. COBOL isn't like that. This doesn't make COBOL bad, but it is very *very* different!